# Subclass of UIView doesn't invoke didSet

Tags: swift, uiview, didset

I have a subclass of UIView named BaseView. In subclass of BaseView I create didSet with some code. In UIViewController I init this subclass of BaseView and he doesn't invoke his didSet

BaseView code:

```
class BaseView: UIView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()
    }

    func setupViews() { }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Subclass of BaseView code:

```
class DetailProductView: BaseView {

var product: Product? {
    didSet {
        productImage.image = UIImage(named: (product?.productImageName)!)
        productTitle.text = product?.title
        productCompositionLabel.text = product?.description
        productPriceLabel.text = "₽" + product!.productPrice!.stringValue
        productWeightLabel.text = product!.productWeight!.stringValue + "г."
    }
}
```

UIViewController code:

```
class DetailProductController: UIViewController {

    var product: Product?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .white

        let productView = DetailProductView(frame: self.view.bounds)
        view.addSubview(productView)
        view.layoutSubviews()
    }
}
```

Comment: First: BaseView is 'UIView' object and your Product cell is 'UITableViewCell' or 'UICollectionViewCell', these components types are different. Second thing is if you want to use your property's 'didSet' statement you should set your ProductCell's 'product' property.

Comment: Oh, I paste a wrong code. I'll fix the question now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything is correct. You created instance of DetailProductView, but you never set any value to it’s `product` property. Thus didSet was never called (cause you didn’t set anything).

If you want it to be called you should set any value to this property.